# Send email when database value equals 5

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to send an email notification to a specific email address. I have a MySQL database in which I hold a product table. Product ID, ProductDescription, and ProductQuantity.

When the Quantity reaches "5" I want to send an automatic email saying that ProductID is out of stock.

Do you have any idea how I can write that in Express js?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

each time you decrease the product quantity retrieve its current quantity then create a if statement

something like this

```
//decrease product quantity

con.query("UPDATE product SET ProductQuantity = value WHERE ProductID = 1")

//retrieve product quantity

let product_quantity = con.query("SELECT ProductQuantity WHERE ProductID = 1")


//send email

if(product_quantity <= 5) {

      send_email();

}
```